# Undefined variable: json in admin/controller/sale/order.php on line 2490

Tags: json, opencart2.x

Not sure if anyone can help however I have found ANOTHER bug/issue in opencart 2. When changing the status of orders I am getting the below message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <

OK

Notice:Undefined variable: json in /vhost/...../www/admin/controller/sale/order.php on line 2490
```

I have tried re-creating a new API user as found in other posts about this without any luck, still gets the same error. I have also tried amended the order.php file to add the extra line for json but this makes no difference so reverted to original order.php file for now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Settings** > **Users** > **API**
2. Create new API and enable it
3. Go to your **Store Settings** and edit it
4. Under **Option tab** and in the Checkout section, select your created API Save the Settings

**and your issue will be solved!**

Answer (score 0):

Change api user was not worked for me.

Replace all admin files (admin folder) with fresh copies. It works for me.

oc version : 2.0.2.0